# Keystore change password details?

Tags: android

I wanted to confirm that "My app is already in the android market with version 1.0,but now I wanted to change the password of my keystore,Now my question is if I will change the password from abc to xyz then in future when I will upload a new version (version 1.1) of my same app into the android market,then the key would be same but the password will change,So by changing the password,am i able to upload the new version of my same app with the password as xyz??

Comment: i dont think so it will create  any problem for you.... just the keystore needs to be the same

Comment: yes i know the keystore would be the same,but I am confuse with password..

Comment: Hi @Kanika Are you able to upload the application to market with same keystore file after changing the password?. Hoping for your valuable response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your keystore password will not affect the keys that the Android build system uses, you can verify this by using [keytool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) to export the key before and after a password change. The keystore password is just there to secure the keystore so that if someone gains access to your .keystore file they will be unable to sign any code using your keys unless they are also able to get your password.